# Cake is NOT able to connect to the database. XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm developing on XAMPP 1.8.1 and running into issues with CakePHP not being able to connect to the database. I've looked around a bit, and others have suggested making sure pdo is enabled, and it is. I know my database settings are correct. I've checked and rechecked them, but I'm still getting:

```
Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.
Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
```

I've set up CakePHP multiple times before, even with XAMPP, and I've never run into this issue.

My database settings are as follows:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/MySQL',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'cakeuser',
    'password' => '*****',
    'database' => 'cake',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you get to the phpMyAdmin page and poke around the DB?  Try some of the stuff [listed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830896/cake-php-mysql-connection) to make sure PDO is enabled.

Comment: You say PDO is enabled, but is pdo_mysql enabled as well?

Comment: PDO is enabled. I have extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll in my php.ini file. It was there by default.

Comment: You must be getting a [`MissingConnectionException` exception](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-MissingConnectionException.html), which is "Used when no connections can be found". Did you restart Apache after installing PDO?

Comment: The output of my phpinfo() lists pdo drivers as enabled for mysql and sqlite as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output of your phpinfo ().  Is there a row titled PDO drivers? What does it say?

Comment: The output of my phpinfo() lists pdo drivers as enabled for mysql and sqlite as well.

Comment: Do you have a phpmyadmin on the same machine as cake?  Is it able to connect?  Is it able to connect with the same credentials?